# Prove that $p(x)$ is a irreducible in $A[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $A$ be an integral domain. Let $P$ be a ideal prime of $A$ and $p(x)\in A[x]$ be a monic polynomial
>   $$p(x)=x^{n}+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1x^{}+a_0$$
>
> Assume that all the coefficients $a_i\in P$ but $a_0\notin P^2$. Then $p(x)$ is a irreducible in $A[x]$.

any suggestions please.

Comment: I think you mean $I$ instead of $P$. This result is know as "Eisenstein criterion". Look it up. Or try looking at what happens modulo $I$

Comment: You may want to google "Eisenstein Criterion"

Answer (score 0):

Consider a reduction $p(x)=q(x)h(x)$. Then we note that since $P$ is prime, $A/P$ is an integral domain, so that $A/P[x]$ is to. Now let $\bar{p}(x)=\bar{q}(x)\bar{h}(x)$ be the image in $A/P$. We have $\bar{p}(x)=x^n$, so that $\bar{q}(x)=x^m$ and $\bar{h}(x)=x^{n-m}$, since if they had any lower, nonzero terms, there product would yield a nonzero term in $\bar{p}(x)$ of sub-maximal degree. Namely, if we assume that $n-m, m>0$, then we have that the constant terms of $q(x)$ and $h(x)$ are in $P$, so that the constant term of $p(x)$, which is the product of constant terms in $q(x)$ and $p(x)$, is in $P^2$, a contradiction.